# Is there any shortcut in eclipse or workaround to go to current methods starting from inside method

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, java, eclipse

Suppose I am inside a method having 900 lines(I know bad programming practice but we come across such situations often). I am at suppose 345 line and I wanted to go to current methods starting(Name) line immediately. How can I do that in eclipse?

This is just an example and the java/jsp file might have many other methods. hence I would appreciate if your answer considers all these factors.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer finally,
If I just use shortcut **ctrl+o and then press enter** Eclipse will take me to the methods name immediatly